DisplayLink turns off laptop screen after login (no external monitors present)
I have a Pluggable 4K Docking Station Triple Monitor that I use with my LG Gram laptop (usb-c connected). I am running Ubuntu Mate 22.04.4 LTS and have version 6.0.0-24 of the DisplayLink software installed (amd64).
I have my 3 external monitors enabled, but I turned the laptop screen OFF since the lid is closed. I also clicked "Apply System-Wide" once I got things arranged so it would remember across reboots (screen shots below).
I shutdown the laptop and took it to a meeting. When I powered it up I got the Ubuntu login screen. After I log in, the screen immediately turns off.
Q1: Why doesn't the DisplayLink software recognize that the only display available is the laptop screen, thus leaving it turned on?
Q2: Is there a shortcut key combo I can use to turn it back on in that case?
thank you,
relayman

